# Calculate a jetplane's distance from my location

Tags: physics, triangulation

So i was sitting outside my workplace and saw this jet flying.

I was really curious if there is a way to calculate the jet's distance between the jet and my location. (I have very little knowledge about math and physics and I'm just really curious on how to solve this thing.)

[image: Problem Image]

I'm looking at the jet maybe on a 50degree angle. There's a fence in front of me and I'm looking at the tip of it maybe on a 45degree angle. (I don't know if this data may help, I'll just put it here anyway.). The distance of the fence from where I'm sitting at is approximately 2 meters. I'm looking at the jet and its tiny figure is moving away at a rate of 1cm/sec in relation to the fence.

Is there a way to solve the distance between me and the jet?

Answer (score 0):

You could continue the triangle between you and the (base of your fence + your height) and top of your fence.

However this only pins down the ratio of height and distance of the plane. You would need either of those to estimate the other by the ratio.